# Extending or increasing horizontal scrollbar width

Tags: canvas, eclipse-plugin, swt, scrollbar, eclipse-rcp

I used the below code to combine two canvas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
shell.setText("Canvas Test");

Composite mainComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);

layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;

mainComp.setLayout(layout);
mainComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, true, true));

final Canvas hwCanvas = new Canvas(mainComp, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
hwCanvas.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
hwCanvas.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
hwCanvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, true));
hwCanvas.getVerticalBar().setVisible(false);

final Canvas traceCanvas = new Canvas(mainComp, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
traceCanvas.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
traceCanvas.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
traceCanvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, true, true));

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
    }
}
display.dispose();
```

}

Is it possible to increase the width(length) of the horizontal scrollbar as shown here 
[snapshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3pxBGD-v-ycVjRYVjBYVnhBMTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your scroll bars to the component that holds the two canvas components, so your horizontal scroll bar can be in charge of the combined overall width of both of them:

```
Composite mainComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
:
final Canvas hwCanvas = new Canvas(mainComp, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);
:
final Canvas traceCanvas = new Canvas(mainComp, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Yes can I do that but if I hide horizontal scrollbar of second canvas and add the horizontal scrollbar to main composite then when I scroll horizontal scrollbar of main composite it scrolls first and second canvas both. I don't want to scroll first canvas and its content. I want to freeze the first canvas and only scrolling should happen to second canvas

Comment: I misunderstood your original question.  Are you saying that when the horizontal scroll bar for the second canvas is not as wide as the canvas itself?